# Working with a css3 key frame slide effect but cant figure out how to configure correctly.. Fiddle included

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

The idea is to have a responsive version of this fiddle(see below) that is 100% wide and has a height of 500px... If I adjust the width of this to 100% it messes up along the end of the animation.. How should I go about making a simple animation like this that will work cross browser, have a width of 100%, be displayed seamlessly, and a switchable height via media queries(I can do the queries part)..

my code: http://jsfiddle.net/hkJsm/
html

```
 <div id="logo"></div>
```

css

```
@-webkit-keyframes slide {
from{
    background-position:575px;
}
to{
    background-position:1725px;
}
}

#logo{
text-align:center;
width:575px;
height:200px;
background:url(http://f.cl.ly/items/0g3q1A203t2A2m182i1k/newbg.png);
-webkit-animation: slide 10s linear infinite;
 }
```

Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is interesting, so I realized the image had to be cropped because in **CSS3** you can't manually flip images, so I've edited it.  It is working in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hkJsm/6/) fiddle, and was fixed by editing [this](http://f.cl.ly/items/0g3q1A203t2A2m182i1k/newbg.png) image to [this](http://i41.tinypic.com/ofpuh0.jpg), and changing the **background-position** property a bit on **to** in the animation:

`background-position:1725px;`

to

`background-position:1645px;`

The image conversions are shown below.

This image[image: Image Before]

To this[image]

Comment: I need it to be seamless.. It gets wonky when you stretch it. open your fiddle, stretch it all the way so the logo is as big as possible and notice how it snaps every so often... any ideas?

Comment: @user3145782 Yes, just edit that part of the image out, or change the location where the image starts its animation.

Comment: could you please show me how to do that with a larger image? or show me how to? I really need to understand this better...

Comment: @user3145782 Edit out the last part

Comment: what does that mean..? can you please post a working fiddle. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can do:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hkJsm/1/

**CSS**

```
 .outer{
     background:url(http://f.cl.ly/items/0g3q1A203t2A2m182i1k/newbg.png);
     -webkit-animation: slide 10s linear infinite;

 }
 #logo{
     min-height: 80px;
 }
```

**HTML**

```
  <div class="outer"><div id="logo"> </div></div>
```

Comment: this works but it isn't seamless when I stretch it out... would I just need to use a photo that say 4000px wide? that way it keeps going and doesn't cut off like this one does when it is stretched?

Comment: Or you can do `width: 100%;` and give `min-width` to logo

Comment: How would i go about making this seamless. when the page is fully stretched it snaps every so often